# Make sure that "Default Category"(id:2) category for current store is anchored

Tags: magento2, category

Was getting error like this when searching for products on store.
What steps can be taken?

**Make sure that "Default Category"(id:2) category for current store is anchored**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure the "Default Category" (id:2) for the current store is anchored, follow these steps:

1. **Navigate to Categories:** This is found under Catalog > Categories.
2. **Select 'Default Category':** You'll see a category tree on the left side. Click on the 'Default Category' (which typically has an ID of 2). This will load the category details on the right side.
3. **Check 'Is Anchor' Option:** On the right side, scroll down to the 'Display Settings' tab and expand it. Here you should see the 'Is Anchor' option.
4. **Set 'Is Anchor' to 'Yes':** If it's not set to 'Yes', change it and click the 'Save' button on the top right of the page.

Finally, clear Magento's cache (System > Cache Management) to ensure your changes take effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if for the store view you are searching products for, anchor tag for the root category is whether enabled.

If not, enable it.

Just reindex the magento setup.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```